# Google apps script to sync two calendars

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two companies(A, B) , I use Google Apps for both.

Company A and Company B uses same conference rooms for meetings.

If company A books a conference room in its google app calendar, Company B won't know that is booked.

So I want a way to sync these two Calendars without sharing two Calendars publicly.

I think google app script would be useful here. I want realtime or 1 min delay sync.

Does google app script is useful here, I can run script on both google accounts.?

How to make authentication automatic?

if not google app script , any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can trigger an Apps Script function to run in a separate account by making an HTTPS GET or POST request to the published URL of the Apps Script Web App.  If you use a GET request then the data must be passed in a search string appended to the URL.  If you use a POST request, then the data must be sent in the payload.  You will need to make permissions settings for the Web App.